# java.net.SocketException: Connection reset - [SSL]

Tags: java, sockets, ssl

In an application java (client/server), with apache and https connection, I have a problem with connections. This is the error I received in the client part:

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at es.stratesys.pos.stratepos.filesync.client.BaseHttpClient.sendAndReceive(BaseHttpClient.java:43)
    at es.stratesys.pos.stratepos.filesync.client.FileSyncClient.retrieveRemoteFolderMetadata(FileSyncClient.java:352)
    at es.stratesys.pos.stratepos.filesync.client.FileSyncClient.syncTopDown(FileSyncClient.java:166)
    at es.stratesys.pos.stratepos.filesync.client.FileSyncClient.synchronize(FileSyncClient.java:144)
    at es.stratesys.pos.stratepos.filesync.client.task.TpvFileSyncTaskManager$1.run(TpvFileSyncTaskManager.java:74)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:53)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

We have install this software in a lot of computers, and only a computer report me this error. This computer have Windows 7 and Java 1.6.0_39 (32 bits). Could you give me any help to find this error? (If you need more information, please let me know)

Comment: Have you checked if the correct certificate is installed on the machine? It looks like the server is dropping the connection for some reason.